# How to reload map component when some value changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have a component that loads a google map according to the Lat and Lng passed, but when I change this value, I need the map to be rendered on the screen

```
  const [getLat, setGetLat] = useState(geoLocation.mapsLat);
  const [getLng, setGetLng] = useState(geoLocation.mapsLng);

  const loadMap = getLat && getLng;


useEffect((previousValue) => {
      const { zipCode } = formValues;

      if (zipCode !== previousValue) {
        console.log('need reload the map');
      }
    },
    [ ]
  );
```

How do I render this fixed part of my code when it happens in console.log?

```
  return (
    {loadMap && (
        <div className="container">
          <label>Map</label>
          <Map lat={getLat} lng={getLng} handleClick={handleSubmit} />
        </div>
      )}
  )
```

Comment: You can use the dependency array of the useEffect to be able to rerender the component, in your first case the dependency array is empty so it will run on mount only

Comment: I don't know why when a change occurs, the component doesn't re-render

Answer (score 0):

```
  const [getLat, setGetLat] = useState(geoLocation.mapsLat);
  const [getLng, setGetLng] = useState(geoLocation.mapsLng);


useEffect((previousValue) => {
      const { zipCode } = formValues;
      setGetLat(geoLocation.mapsLat);
      setGetLng(geoLocation.mapsLng);
   },[geoLocation.mapsLat,geoLocation.mapsLng]);
```

```
  return (
    {getLat && getLng && (
        <div className="container">
          <label>Map</label>
          <Map lat={getLat} lng={getLng} handleClick={handleSubmit} />
        </div>
      )}
  )
```

The above code must resolve your problem.
whenever your `zipCode` value changes the component will rerender and your ui would be updated.

Comment: That didn't solve it =( I put some more information in the question to be clearer

Comment: I tried to do that, but the view map doesn't re-render. Is there any way to force or reload?

Comment: where have you defined, geoLocation ?

Comment: It has a selector that takes this value from the state: const geoLocation = useSelector(getGeolocationSelector);

And the state is changing but the map won't reload

Comment: Can you create it in sandbox... so that we have a better idea of your code.

Comment: Can you also share your Map component

Comment: I'm using this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader